# Scrapinghub shub deploy error - Error: Deploy failed (400): project: non_field_errors

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapinghub

When I try to shub deploy it in the cloud and getting the following error.

```
Error: Deploy failed (400):
project: non_field_errors
```

My current setup is as follows.

```
def __init__(self, startUrls, *args, **kwargs):

    self.keywords = ['sales','advertise','contact','about','policy','terms','feedback','support','faq']

    self.startUrls = startUrls

    self.startUrls = json.loads(self.startUrls)

    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def start_requests(self):

    for url in self.startUrls:

        yield Request(url=url)
```

Comment: Post your full spider code, is the class name of your spider really is `MySpider`?? and do you have a `name` attribute in this class?

Comment: @Umair  Solution found. Very simple as usuall)). But your comment about the classname si itneresting. Should it me the same as the className of my spider? Say like this one - class CodeSpider(scrapy.Spider)?

Comment: Yes it should be same as your real class name. Also, i had asked you about logging out and logging back in in your previous question you asked.

Comment: Yeah. You are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stupid me.
The problem was that I was logged in under different SH account.
So the project I tried to deploy did not exist.
Obviously the error message could be more user frienly. But well.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Helped me instantly.